# Please re-open question with edited title

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, openid

Please reopen. I edited title to be clearer. I am asking verification of a claim made in a video.

[Do doctors recommend that ears checked annually?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/24248/do-doctors-recommend-that-ears-checked-annually)

Comment: The problem isn't that your question is unclear. The problem is it asks for personal medical advice. I've already given you [the link](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/how-long-can-this-site-be-popular-if-everybody-is-asked-to-see-a-doctor/748#748) that explains why.

Comment: Even with the original title the content of the question appeared clear that it was asking for verification of the claim about ear exams. I have reopened the question.